# Java NIO with InputStream.available()

Tags: java, sockets, nio

Good day.

I'm using NIO multiplexing and I don't want to allocate additional buffers in my app till I will sure I have enough bytes in socket to read the entire application packet. Each application packet contains 4 bytes of packet length (header) and following bytes of packet body. I want to read 4 bytes of packet length if they are available and then following bytes of packet body if they are available. So, the code can look something like that:

```java
private final ByteBuffer READ_BUFFER = ByteBuffer.wrap(new byte[READ_BUFFER_SIZE]);
...
Iterator<SelectionKey> selectedKeys = selector.selectedKeys().iterator();

while (selectedKeys.hasNext())
{
    SelectionKey key = selectedKeys.next();
    selectedKeys.remove();

    Connection con = (Connection) key.attachment();

    switch (key.readyOps())
    {
        case SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT:
            acceptConnection(key);
            break;
        case SelectionKey.OP_READ:
            readPacket(key, con);    //**
    }
}
...
private final void readPacket(final SelectionKey key, final Connection con)
{   
    READ_BUFFER.clear();
    int result = -2;

    try
    {
        result = con.read(READ_BUFFER);
    }
    catch (IOException e) {}

    //* packet processing goes here
}
```

In * we can obtain:

1. less than 4 bytes to read header;
2. 4 bytes for header but not enough bytes for packet body
3. enough bytes to read N packets (header + body), but part of (N+1)
   packet

In either of 3 cases I have to store the readed data in additional ByteBuffer, as READ_BUFFER will be used for the next connection in **.

What I want to do:

```java
public class Connection
{
    private final ByteChannel byteChannel;
    private final InputStream in;
    private int lastPacketSize = -1;

    Connection(final Socket socket)
    {
        byteChannel = socket.getChannel();
        in = socket.getInputStream();
    }

    int read(final ByteBuffer buf) throws IOException
    {
        return byteChannel.read(buf);
    }

    int available()
    {
        return in.available();
    }

    void setLastPacketSize(int size)
    {
        lastPacketSize = size;
    }

    int getLastPacketSize()
    {
        return lastPacketSize;
    }
}

private final IntBuffer HEADER_BUFFER = IntBuffer.wrap(new int[1]);
private final void readPacket(final SelectionKey key, final Connection con)
{
    int packetSize = con.getLastPacketSize();
    if (packetSize < 0)
    {
        if (con.available() < 4) return;

        int result = -2;
        HEADER_BUFFER.clear();
        try
        {
            result = con.read(HEADER_BUFFER);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {}

        if (result != 4)
        {
            closeConnection(key);
            return;
        }

        packetSize = HEADER_BUFFER.get();
        con.setLastPacketSize(packetSize);
    }

    if (con.available() < packetSize) return;

    result = -2;

    READ_BUFFER.clear();
    READ_BUFFER.limit(packetSize);
    try
    {
        result = con.read(READ_BUFFER);
    }
    catch (IOException e) {}

    if (result != packetSize)
    {
        closeConnection(key);
        return;
    }
    con.setLastPacketSize(-1);

    //packet processing goes here
}
```

I have found that under the hood Socket's InputStream uses ioctl(fd, FIONREAD, pbytes) on Linux. Can I rely on con.available() in this scenario or it can fail? If it can fail what are the reasons for that and how to improve this code to overcome these reasons?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using non-blocking mode you can't use an `InputStream` at all. You can't have ever run this code.

There's not much point in what you're trying to do. Just read every time OP_READ fires until you have enough data to process.

Comment: My idea was to read only packet length bytes and process packet and the rest will remain in socket buffers. In such case I need only buffer with length >= packetLength. If I have too many clients and these clients produce too many packets, they will fill up socket buffers, then application level buffers, and then TCP flow control will require the clients to stop sending more data. So, each of these clients will require additional memory.